# Vue ref type is not inferred correctly when using function as initializer

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I would like to know why my ref type is inferred from the "shape" of the returned value of a function and not its return type.

I have this code

```
import type { ResourcesConfig } from '@aws-amplify/core'

const getLoginConfig = (): ResourcesConfig => {
  const {
    VITE_APP_AWS_USER_POOL_ID: userPoolId = '',
    VITE_APP_AWS_USER_POOL_CLIENT_ID: userPoolClientId = '',
    VITE_APP_AWS_HOSTED_UI_DOMAIN: domain = '',
    VITE_APP_AWS_REDIRECT_SIGN_IN: redirectSignIn = [],
    VITE_APP_AWS_REDIRECT_SIGN_OUT: redirectSignOut = [],
    VITE_APP_AWS_OAUTH_SCOPES: scopes = [],
  } = import.meta.env

  return {
    Auth: {
      Cognito: {
        userPoolId,
        userPoolClientId,
        loginWith: {
          oauth: {
            domain,
            redirectSignIn,
            redirectSignOut,
            scopes,
            responseType: 'code',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }
}

const loginConfig = ref<ResourcesConfig>(getLoginConfig())
```

And this is how loginConfig gets typed

```
const loginConfig: Ref<{
    API?: {
        REST: Record<string, APIRestConfig>;
        GraphQL?: {
            endpoint: string;
            region?: string | undefined;
            apiKey?: string | undefined;
            customEndpoint?: string | undefined;
            customEndpointRegion?: string | undefined;
            defaultAuthMode: GraphQLAuthMode;
            modelIntrospection?: {
                ...;
            } | undefined;
        } | undefined;
    } | {
        ...;
    } | undefined;
    ... 6 more ...;
    Geo?: {
        ...;
    } | undefined;
}>
```

instead of

`const loginConfig: Ref<ResourcesConfig>`

I managed to make it work using `const loginConfig = ref<ResourcesConfig>(getLoginConfig()) as Ref<ResourcesConfig>` but I would like to avoid using `as` if possible.

Even `const loginConfig = ref<ResourcesConfig>(getLoginConfig() as ResourcesConfig)` was not okay so I assume there's something wrong with the ref typing.

Comment: What problem do you have exactly with inferred type? Does `const loginConfig: Ref<ResourcesConfig> = ...` cause type incompatibility? This is how ref() works, it traverses  fields and unwraps other refs, which is documented behaviour. The result may differ from ref<ResourcesConfig>

Answer (score 0):

Its works just fine, Vue infers type from the `<ResourceConfig>` you provided. The only "difference" is that the intellisense displays the properties of the `ResourceConfig`, and not only the name of the interface.

Please check [ResourcesConfig's docs](https://www.jsdocs.io/package/@aws-amplify/core#ResourcesConfig) so you can see that intellisense displays the details of the `ResourceConfig` itself.